# How django-rest-framwork shows data while the relavant table is actually empty?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project which has these models:

```py
class PlaceQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def filter_by_province(self, province, lang='se'):
        query = self.filter(province=province, is_published=True)
        .annotate(thumbnail_uuid=models.F('image_album__default__uuid'))
        .prefetch_related()
        if lang == 'se':
            return query.annotate(city_name=models.F('city__alt_names__name'),)
        else:
            return query.annotate(city_name=models.F('city__name'))
```

```py
class BasePlaceModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = PlaceQuerySet.as_manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50))
    ...
```

```py
class Hotel(BasePlace):
    popularity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    ...
```

For some reasons i need to create a new Hotel model with different fields. So I add this to my models.py:

```py
class HotelModel(BasePlace):
    new_popularity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    ...
```

Eventually I want to access my new *HotelModel* with DRF. Here is my code:

```py
class NewHotelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = HotelSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )
    queryset = HotelModel.objects.all()


class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'blahblah'
        )
```

The weird part is when I query the NewHotelViewSet it responses with data while this new model is empty. Executing **HotelModel.objects.all()** shows same result. I even checked Postgres and it has no data.

Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks.

Comment: please show full `class PlaceQuerySet`

Comment: @BearBrown Edited. Could it be from the similar naming? postgres shows me there are two tables: `place_hotel` and `place_hotelmodel`